# How do I make a bot say a certain message when it first joins a server?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot say a certain message when it first joins a Discord Server, so when the bot first joins a Discord Server, it will say something along the lines of "Hello everyone....". I looked at a lot of sources but none seem to be JavaScript. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.on('guildCreate', joinedGuild => {
//Blah
}
```

Documentation for the `guildCreate` handler [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate).

Comment: So Like:
`

0
down vote
accept
client.on('guildCreate', joinedGuild => {
hello welcome!
}
`
im not sure because i never really look at it. if you can give an exmaple that would be nice

Comment: Yes, but that's not how you send a message to a server's channel by the way. From the guild parameter, you should grab a channel from the list of channels in the guild. You can send the hello message to the server's default channel if it exists: `joinedGuild.defaultChannel.send("Hello").catch(console.log("No default channel!"))`.

Comment: im new to all of this so let me make sure
client.on('guildCreate', joinedGuild => {
joinedGuild.defaultChannel.send("Hello").catch(console.log("No default channel!"))
}

Comment: You can test the codes by yourself and make changes if you need to. Also, if you are relatively new to making a Discord bot or javascript, you can search up tutorials on youtube.

Comment: guild.defaultChannel is deprecated.

Comment: A guild might not have any text channels

Comment: @AndréPaulo thats what the catch statement is for... and the reason I indicated `if it exists`

Comment: It will fall into the catch more times it will actually work, only old servers that didn't get auto updated for some weird reason might have that channel

Comment: But in the end, it is still up to the OP how he wants to send a message to the server. I was showing him very basic example and had warned that the code would not work properly if the server does not have a default channel.

Comment: Did not work with no errors tried
    Client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
      message.channel.send("hello!");
    });  and yours did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an event listener to execute whenever it registers a new guild.

For example:

```
Client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
  // Code to be executed whenever a new guild is registered
});
```

You can find out more [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate).

Comment: The reason for that is because we have the same method of solving this specified problem.

Comment: Yeah Kaynn answered 12 hours earlier - it's best to look at previous answers to make sure you don't add the same answer.

Comment: That question isn't accepted yet, indicating that the question is still open to further answers regardless of their similarities.

Comment: "Regardless of their similarities"? Do you think it would be useful if two people answer almost the exact same way to one of your questions? Doesn't sound useful at all, in my opinion. I didn't flag your answer or anything, I just thought I'd provide my comment. Do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Did not work with no errors
tried
    Client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
      message.channel.send("hello!");
    });

Comment: The event listener is passing, so you need to find the guild’s default channel and send it there.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: guild.defaultChannel.send(“message”)